# Energy conservation applied to a generator

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

If a turbine runs with a kinetic energy of some joules, the electricity produced must also have the same power given out, according to the energy conservation law.

Now if the electric flux is increased the voltage can be increased. But the current through the output circuit must be limited.

Does it happen ?

Comment: Note that you've described an ideal, I.e. lossless, system here. In a real turbine/generator, some of the energy is lost to friction or heat or deformation of the parts, etc. If you total up all *those* expenditures, plus the electricity out, you'll get your original total back again. Measuring since against only electrical output gets you a lower output than input.

Comment: the answer seems unclear and i consider the ideal case here @Asher